# Creating a C Buffer From the ARM to the VideoCore on RPi3

Tags: c, assembly, arm, raspberry-pi3, bare-metal

I am looking into the the **hello world** of bare metal on **RPi3**, which is turning on the ACT LED.

There many good resources:

1. Some in [assembly for Pi 1](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/)
2. [David Welch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16007/old-timer)'s excellent [baremetal tutorial](https://github.com/dwelch67/raspberrypi/tree/master/baremetal) for Pi 1 and 2
3. and his [blinker01](https://github.com/dwelch67/raspberrypi/tree/master/blinker01) example for Pi 1 and 2

The **Pi3** unfortunately has moved the LED's off GPIO.  You instead have to [send a message](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1332#issuecomment-194353863) to the VideoCore (GPU) in its mailbox to turn on the LED.

The [documentation](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/wiki/Mailbox-property-interface) states the buffer content of that message as follows:

> u32: buffer size in bytes (including the header values, the end tag and padding)
>
> u32: buffer request/response code
>
> ```
>  Request codes:
>     0x00000000: process request
>     All other values reserved 
>  Response codes:
>     0x80000000: request successful
>     0x80000001: error parsing request
>     All other values reserved
> ```
>
> u8...: sequence of concatenated tags
>
> u32: 0x0 (end tag)
>
> u8...: padding

I was able to get [this assembly example](https://github.com/adamransom/bare_metal/blob/master/led01/src/kernel.s) successfully running on the Pi 3.  The ACT LED turns on and stays on.

But my point in doing this is to learn bare metal `C`.  I am new to `C` but I understand enough to explain what the following function does:

```
/**
*** This is my own summary ** so likely incorrect
* 
* Assigns the address of the Mailbox which is 0x3f00b880 to the mailbox variable
* 
* Then waits until Mailbox 0 which the GPU uses as interrupt to the ARM;
* basically saying I am ready for your message.
* 
* The function then puts the address of the message buffer
* plus the channel to be used; in this case channel 4 for ACT LED
*/
unsigned int MailboxWrite ( unsigned int fbinfo_addr, unsigned int channel )
{
    unsigned int mailbox;

    mailbox=0x3f00b880;
    while(1)
    {
        if((GET32(mailbox+0x18)&0x80000000)==0) break;
    }
    PUT32(mailbox+0x20,fbinfo_addr+channel);
    return(0);
}
```

The problem I am having (and maybe it's because it's late at night and I have been at this for several hours) is I am not sure how to construct the buffer.

My thinking is to make an `int` array that looks like:

```
# ?? buffer size in bytes
# 0 is the request code
# 0x00038041 Tag ID (SET_GPIO_STATE)
# 8 value buffer size
# 0 Request/response size
# 130 ACT_LED pin number
# 1 Turn it on
# 0 End tag
[??,0,0x00038041,8,0,130,1,0]
```

How should I calculate the buffer size?  Is it the size of the array?

So would I add just a `0` as the first element, then run `sizeof` and update the array?

```
int[] buffer = [0,0,0x00038041,8,0,130,1,0];
buffer[0] = sizeof(buffer)
```

Comment: the raspberry pi forum at the raspberry pi site has covered this topic and there are many examples out there no doubt.

Comment: Try asking/looking here https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's bad form to answer my own question but I hope it helps someone.

Thanks to the comment from @old_timer I search the [bare metal](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewforum.php?f=72&sid=0336afe301622b6425f79f0f63c1e7b7) forum and found this [solution](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=169582#p1193028):

```
void set_PI3LED(bool on) {
    uint32_t __attribute__((aligned(16))) mailbox_message[8];
    mailbox_message[0] = sizeof(mailbox_message);
    mailbox_message[1] = 0;
    mailbox_message[2] = 0x38041;
    mailbox_message[3] = 8;
    mailbox_message[4] = 8;
    mailbox_message[5] = 130;
    mailbox_message[6] = (uint32_t)on;
    mailbox_message[7] = 0;
    mailbox_write(MB_CHANNEL_TAGS, mailbox_ARM_to_VC(&mailbox_message[0]));
    mailbox_read(MB_CHANNEL_TAGS);
}
```

It's nice to know I wasn't too far off and it's good to know I now have the exact syntax I need.